# Create TabView at runtime?

Tags: android

I need to create tab View at runtime by using java code .

Note:
 without using xml design

Answer (score 1):

Create TabHost, TabWidget in XML and then add TAbHost.TabSpec at run time.

Comment: Without using xml i need to create the tabview.

Comment: Try creating the same XML code in Java file, and then set the contentView to that. Then add tabhost dynamically.... It will be a bit lengthy process. But yes you can give it a try at least.